# Are Stack Overflow profiles indexed by search engines?

Tags: discussion, search-engine

Is it possible to find a given user's about page by searching for information contained in it on google?

-EDIT-
I managed to find my profile by searching for text on my "about me" box, but couldn't manage to find it by searching for my full name, even if I add the words "stack overflow" to the query.

Comment: Can't reproduce, you are first: http://i.stack.imgur.com/v9bJf.png

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, if I search for the first paragraph of text in my "about me" box, my Stack Overflow user profile is the first result returned by Google, so that information does appear to be indexed.

Comment: I now also managed to find my profile by searching for text on my "about me" box, but couldn't manage to find my profile by searching for my full name, even if I add the words "stack overflow" to the query.

Comment: @Cezar That's because your full name is only visible to you, moderators, and employees of Stack Exchange.  Google can't scrape that particular piece of information from your profile.  Use your full name as your display name if you do want search engines to find you on Stack Overflow.